Unable to GET nginx welcome page from Hetzner Ubuntu 24.04. LTS server with custom domain and docker
I am trying to set up a server and have problems GETing the standard nginx welcome page.
My setup:

Hetzner VPS with Ubuntu 24.04. LTS and Docker
I did basic server hardening (updated ubuntu, restricted ssh root access, changed ssh port, set up Fail2Ban)
I did not touch iptables / nftables yet (see screenshots below), there is no firewall active in the Hetzner cloud console
I bought a domain and changed DNS settings (two A and two AAAA entries) in the Hetzner DNS console (see picture below). I waited a day and get now the correct ip addresses on my local machine, when running nslookup for my domain (e.g. nslookup example.com)
Docker is running on the Ubuntu server with the official nginx image (docker run -it --rm -d -p 8080:80 nginx)
I can ping the domain from my local machine and see the matching logs on my Ubuntu server with tcpdump ip proto \\icmp

My problem:
I can not connect to port 8080 of my server, to see the standard welcome page of nginx.

curl example.com returns Connection refused for IPv4 and Network is unreachable for IPv6
Postman returns Error: connect ECONNREFUSED for the call GET examlpe.com
Browser (Firefox 129.0.2) is unable to load the page, the developer tools show the error NS_ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Did I miss something? How can I debug this issue further?
Screenshots:





I found the problem:

I had no firewall in place in the hetzner cloud console. Hetzner blocks all inbound traffic in case of no firewall. So I added a firewall and allowed ports for http, https and ssh.
My DNS entry for the IPv6 address was wrong. I used (example address) 2222:2222:2222:2222:: (wrong) instead of 2222:2222:2222:2222::1 (correct).
I changed the mapping of the docker ports, to 80 instead of 8080 (docker run -it --rm -d -p 80:80 nginx).

Thanks reddit user u/namesisfortombstones for some helpful hints!
Now I am finally able to see the nginx welcome page from the browser.
